# ASP.NET 3.5 button control event handlers

Tags: asp.net, .net, button

So I had this question asked for a pre-interview screening test and I'm pretty sure *none* of the answers listed are correct.  I looked it up to make sure and I can't find any of them.  Can someone confirm?

> Which of the following event handlers belongs to an ASP.NET button control?
>
> 1. ServerOnClick
> 2. ServerClick
> 3. OnServerClick
> 4. OnServer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ServerClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputbutton.serverclick.aspx) is an event of the control `HtmlInputButton` which is what you get when you add `runat=server` to a html-button.

So it's a button and it's a server-control. Hence it might be the correct answer.

Comment: Bear with me because I hate WebForms and despise server controls, but an `HtmlInputButton` is *not* the same as an ASP.NET button control `<asp:Button ... />` correct?

Comment: No, it's a different type. A [`Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx) is in the webcontrol- and a `HtmlInputButton` is in the  htmlcontrol-namespace. But it's also a serverside "button" control.

Comment: Just saw your edit and it looks like I have a point that the question is silly.  To give you some context, the previous question was "what extension do ASP.NET pages have?"  If `OnClick` or `Click` were answers I would've picked one of those.

Comment: To make things even more convoluted, `OnServerClick` actually raises that event for an `HtmlInputButton`

Comment: <asp:Button .../> is rendered as <input type="button" />. <button> is an HTMLButton, not an HTMLInputButton. I agree the test question can be phrased better, but that might be the intention.

Comment: You've lost me there. `Click` is the event and `OnClick` the event-handler. The extension of ASP.NET pages  is `aspx`. `OnServerClick` is the event handler for the click event of a html button on serverside..

Comment: @Tim: sorry, Enter already submitted the comment; I just want to state there is also a <button> / <asp:HTMLButton>.

Comment: @gerd: Well, the question can really be phrased better. But the `ServerClick` is an event of an ASP.NET(serverside) button control.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I hate web forms! we are left to debate about that event triggers what and what event bubbles where, for crying out loud its the web there only the request and the response we need to ever worry about, MVC all the way :-)

Comment: @Ricky.G My point exactly.  If you're going to ask what the extension of an ASP.NET page is, the other questions should be fairly straightforward and definitely shouldn't involve this level of interpretation complexity.